# How can I link MSN call function on a website?

Tags: html, msn, msn-messenger, windows-live-messenger

I want to create an icon to my website what can call me on MSN when it's clicked. I like something like this with Skype:

```
 <a href="call:myskypeid">Click here to call me on Skype</a>
```

Not necessary to do a call, chat window open is good too.

Is there any way?

Comment: Personally i haven't seen anything like it anywhere, but then again I don't use MSN. This feature depends on the MSN messenger supporting it. Do you have any indication that it does?

Comment: I don't know... maybe this is not possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googled a bit, and found msnim: protocol on this webpage: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1157/msn-messenger-msnim-hyperlink-command-codes/

Can't test, have no MSN messenger.